# Non-linear regression between two series with mismatched X axes

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, regression

I have two data series. I wish to find the linear regression to take a value from series 1 (raw sensor data) and calculate the closest point from series 2 (calibration data) inside my device. However, while they use the same units, the two series have X axes in different increments; Series 1 increments in steps of 10, series 2 in steps of 6-10 depending on sensor value, so I can't simply calculate the regression between the two series.

How do I align them on the same axis so that I can obtain a regression? From previous work/datasheets I'm expecting a low order polynomial.

Example data:

```
Time (mS)   Force (N)    Time (mS)  Raw value
15000       22.14       14998       287.6
15010       22.26       15007       288.6
15020       22.34       15016       288.8
15030       22.58       15024       288
15040       22.78       15033       287.6
15050       22.96       15042       287.6
15060       23.04       15051       287.4
15070       23.12       15060       287.8
15080       23.28       15069       288.6
15090       23.44       15078       288.8
15100       23.68       15086       288.6
```

Thanks!

Comment: please post some sample data with desired results, it's currently difficult to understand your problem

Comment: @MátéJuhász added!

Comment: How you want to match the data? Just use times where both series has value? Calculate some interpolation? ...

Comment: @MátéJuhász interpolation would be nice!

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.g. this formula:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(F:F,MATCH(A2,E:E,0)),IF(A2<MAX(E:E), FORECAST(A2,OFFSET($E$1,MATCH(A2,E:E,1)-1,1,2,1),OFFSET($E$1,MATCH(A2,E:E,1)-1,0,2,1)),""))`

This will first look for match exact time from raw values, and if it doesn't find, then use `FORECAST` function to interpolate based on previous and next time points.

[image]